# Correct syntax for SQL UPDATE where value to be set is a SELECT

Tags: sql

Can someone set me straight on the correct syntax for this statement?

I am trying to update a new field in table `rounds` with an average of a field in table `holes` where `rounds.id` is stored as a foreign key.

```
UPDATE `rounds` SET drivingDistance_avg_per_hole = 
SELECT SUM(holes.drivingDistance)/COUNT(holes.drivingDistance) as avg 
FROM `holes`, `rounds` 
WHERE holes.drivingDistance != '' 
AND holes.round = rounds.id
```

Sure would appreciate the lesson!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your database. Standard SQL doesn't have the FROM syntax with UPDATE and some databases don't support it. In that case this ought to work:

```
UPDATE `rounds` SET drivingDistance_avg_per_hole = (
SELECT SUM(holes.drivingDistance)/COUNT(holes.drivingDistance) as avg 
FROM `holes`
WHERE holes.drivingDistance != '' 
AND holes.round = rounds.id )
```

The key points are that the subselect has to be in parentheses, and that you *don't* want to include the destination table in the subselect because then you're selecting all rows of the table whereas you only care about the rows of `holes` that match the corresponding row from `rounds`.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I definitely learned something new there!